# How to validate GitHub webhook with Deno?

Tags: javascript, github, deno

I'm trying to make a GitHub webhook server with Deno, but I cannot find any possible way to do the validation.

This is my current attempt using [webhooks-methods.js](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks-methods.js):

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import { verify } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@octokit/webhooks-methods?dts";

const app = new Application();

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next();
  } catch (_err) {
    ctx.response.status = 500;
  }
});

const secret = "...";

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  const signature = ctx.request.headers.get("X-Hub-Signature-256");
  if (signature) {
    const payload = await ctx.request.body({ type: "text" }).value;
    const result = await verify(secret, payload, signature);
    console.log(result);
  }
  ctx.response.status = 200;
});
```

The `verify` function is returning `false` every time.

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear: What's not working as expected? What is the problem that you are facing? (See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: I edited the question telling what's the problem.

Comment: I've not used oak much yet. Are you certain `body({ type: "text" }).value` is correct? [`verify`](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks-methods.js#verify) expects a string. If it is receiving something else then that could explain why your code isn't working as you expected.

Comment: @mfulton26 Yes, that's [the signature](https://doc.deno.land/https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.2.0/mod.ts/~/Request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is very close. The [GitHub webhook documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#delivery-headers) details the signature header schema. The value is a digest algorithm prefix followed by the signature, in the format of `${ALGO}=${SIGNATURE}`:

```
X-Hub-Signature-256: sha256=d57c68ca6f92289e6987922ff26938930f6e66a2d161ef06abdf1859230aa23c
```

So, you need to extract the signature from the value (omitting the prefix):

```ts
const signatureHeader = request.headers.get("X-Hub-Signature-256");
const signature = signatureHeader.slice("sha256=".length);
```

> **Update**: Starting in [release version `3.0.1`](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks-methods.js/releases/tag/v3.0.1) of [`octokit/webhooks-methods.js`](https://github.com/octokit/webhooks-methods.js), it is no longer necessary to manually extract the signature from the header — that task is handled by the `verify` function. The code in the answer has been updated to reflect this change.

---

Here's a complete, working example that you can simply copy + paste into a project or playground on [Deno Deploy](https://deno.com/deploy):

`gh-webhook-logger.ts`:

```ts
import { assert } from "https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/testing/asserts.ts";

import {
  Application,
  NativeRequest,
  Router,
} from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts";

import type { ServerRequest } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/types.d.ts";

import { verify } from "https://esm.sh/@octokit/webhooks-methods@3.0.2?pin=v106";

// In actual usage, use a private secret:
// const SECRET = Deno.env.get("SIGNING_SECRET");

// But for the purposes of this demo, the exposed secret is:
const SECRET = "Let me know if you found this to be helpful!";

type GitHubWebhookVerificationStatus = {
  id: string;
  verified: boolean;
};

// Because this uses a native Request,
// it can be used in other contexts besides Oak (e.g. `std/http/serve`):
async function verifyGitHubWebhook(
  request: Request,
): Promise<GitHubWebhookVerificationStatus> {
  const id = request.headers.get("X-GitHub-Delivery");

  // This should be more strict in reality
  assert(id, "Not a GH webhhok");

  const signatureHeader = request.headers.get("X-Hub-Signature-256");
  let verified = false;

  if (signatureHeader) {
    const payload = await request.clone().text();
    verified = await verify(SECRET, payload, signatureHeader);
  }

  return { id, verified };
}

// Type predicate used to access native Request instance
// Ref: https://github.com/oakserver/oak/issues/501#issuecomment-1084046581
function isNativeRequest(r: ServerRequest): r is NativeRequest {
  // deno-lint-ignore no-explicit-any
  return (r as any).request instanceof Request;
}

const webhookLogger = new Router().post("/webhook", async (ctx) => {
  assert(isNativeRequest(ctx.request.originalRequest));
  const status = await verifyGitHubWebhook(ctx.request.originalRequest.request);
  console.log(status);
  ctx.response.status = 200;
});

const app = new Application()
  .use(webhookLogger.routes())
  .use(webhookLogger.allowedMethods());

// The port is not important in Deno Deploy
await app.listen({ port: 8080 });
```

Comment: This is broken in the latest version of Oak. The `ctx.request.originalRequest` has no member `request`.

Comment: @roj1512 Yes, it looks like between releases [`10.2.1` and `10.3.0`](https://github.com/oakserver/oak/compare/v10.2.1...v10.3.0#diff-ac2c89c169fc30ecc5e48c5b830c4c2b67fc5976671d9ebe66bf6c8579687367) oak's API was changed to prevent access to the native [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) for some reason. That's strange and I'm really not sure why... perhaps it was in effort towards compatibility with Node.js. ‍♂️

Comment: @roj1512 I opened [an issue](https://github.com/oakserver/oak/issues/501) for you about this. You can subscribe to it in order to get updates if you are interested.

Comment: @roj1512 I updated my answer with a fix for the latest breaking changes in oak.

Comment: It seems broken again, I still can't seem to get the native request. Is this basically the full text of the body and the full text of the headers? Or just the body?

Comment: I think the answer is just the body, and to get the text of the body is much simpler now: `await req.body({ type: 'text' }).value` you dont need the NativeRequest any more. I was able to verify the signature correctly using that method.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71076989/how-to-validate-github-webhook-with-deno/71088170?noredirect=1#comment129639516_71088170) @justin.m.chase I’m not sure whether or not you read the code and comments: I specifically wrote this answer to be generic, working with a native `Request`, so that it remains useful even apart from Oak.

Comment: @524F4A Thanks for the [update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71088170/3). I also [pinned the esm build version](https://esm.sh/#:~:text=Pin%20the%20build%20version) for the webhooks import.